# Obtain unrelated data

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get data that is not related through a query between three tables, but I have not achieved the feat.

In my case I have three tables

- Brands
- Categories
- Assignment (It is the intercept table between Marks and Categories)

The relationship between brands and categories is many to many in this case, because a brand can have several categories or product lines, or a line of product or category, can be in several brands or be produced by several. For example

Nestle, which is a brand, can produce biscuits, chocolates, and Colombina, produces cookies and chocolates. If you look closely, both produce cookies, but one produces chocolate and the other chocolatina.

Then, I want to know how to obtain, in case of selecting Nestle, to obtain Chocolate, since that does not produce it, or if there are several registered in the database, to obtain all the lines or categories that do not have referenced to this brand.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

For MS-Access, you have to use an equivalent of MINUS operator in ORACLE/MYSQL. It can be done in this case as :

```
select distinct a.* 
from 

( select m.Nombre_marca, c.nombre_categoria from 
Marcas m, categorias c) a

left outer join

(select m1.Nombre_marca, c1.nombre_categoria 
from T_marc_categ mc 
join Marcas m1 on m1.Id_marca_a = mc.nomb_marca
join categorias c1 on c1.Id_categoria_auto = mc.nomb_linea) b

on (a.nombre_marca=b.nombre_marca and 
    a.nombre_categoria = b.nombre_categoria)
where b.nombre_marca is null and 
      b.nombre_categoria is null
```